# Set button's state depending on the global state in Flex 4

Tags: flex4

How can I set my button's state to "over" when , for example , my global state is "Home"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK the problem was that my button had a custom skin. So the only thing I had to to was to write

> if(currentState == "Home") {
>   mybutton.skin.setCurrentState("over",true); }